# First time using constructors

Tags: java

It compiles just fine... but throws a "`java.lang.NullPointerException`" error on  when I try to enter the **index** (as an integer). I thought I already gave index an int type so I'm not sure why this happens.

I'm new to java so if you guys have any pointers on something else I need to look into or try those tips, would be appreciated as well.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class LineEditor
{
  public static void main (String [ ] args)
  {
    //variables
    String myLine;
    String str;
    int index;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //creates original myLine
    myLine = new String ("Computer Science");
    System.out.println ("The original string of text is: " + myLine);

    //variable inputs
    System.out.println("Enter a string to alter myLine: ");
    str = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Enter an index for the string to be inserted at: ");
    index = scan.nextInt();

    Insert insert = new Insert(str, index);

    System.out.println ("The altered string is: " + insert.strIntoMyLine());
  }
}

class Insert
{
  String str;
  int index;
  String myLine;

  public Insert (String s, int i)
  {
      str = s;
      index = i;
  }

  String strIntoMyLine()
   {
      String part1;
      String part2;
      part1 = myLine.substring (0, index);
      part2 = myLine.substring (index);
      return (part1 + str + part2);
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your exception/ stacktrace here.

Comment: Please give your questions a more descriptive title, so that other users with a similar problem can find it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is nothing present in `myLine`.

Replace `Insert insert = new Insert(str, index);` with `Insert insert = new Insert(str, index,myLine);`.

and `public Insert (String s, int i)` with `public Insert (String s, int I, String myLine)`

Also

`this.myLine = myLine;` in the constructor

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCHHHHHHHHHHHH

Comment: @S.Kim After posting questions on On StackOverflow, please accept the answer that solved your problem, to help other users with a similar problem find the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

your constructor should be

```
public Insert(String s, int i, String r) {
    str = s;
    num = i;
    myLine = r;
}
```

and pass value  like this "Insert insert = new Insert(str, index,myLine);"